# Mark projected min and max in 3D surface-/contourplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using the standard matplotlib surfaceplot as an example here.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)][1]][1]
```

[image: Example plot with two extrema]

I would like to mark the two extrema of the surface with a "X" on their respective position on the contour.
How can this be achieved?

I tried:

```
max_column = np.argmax(np.max(Z, axis=0))
max_row = np.argmax(np.max(Z, axis=1))

min_column = np.argmin(np.min(Z, axis=0))
min_row = np.argmin(np.min(Z, axis=1))

target = [max_row,max_column,0] 


ax.plot([target[0]],[target[1]],[0],'r',marker = u'X',markersize = 8)
```

I guess I need somehow the projected coordinates.

Additionally I would like to draw a hairline-cross with lines on the 2D plane where the extrema are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to find out the points corresponding to the minimum and maximum of the `Z` array.
You can then plot those points, where setting one of the coordinates to the values of the respective `offset` from the contour lets them be projected.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=8, cstride=8, alpha=0.3)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='z', offset=-100, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='x', offset=-40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)
cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z, zdir='y', offset=40, cmap=cm.coolwarm)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_xlim(-40, 40)
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_ylim(-40, 40)
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
ax.set_zlim(-100, 100)

# calc index of min/max Z value
xmin, ymin = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(Z), Z.shape)
xmax, ymax = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(Z), Z.shape)

# min max points in 3D space (x,y,z)
mi = (X[xmin,ymin], Y[xmin,ymin], Z.min())
ma = (X[xmax, ymax], Y[xmax, ymax], Z.max())

# Arrays for plotting, 
# first row for points in xplane, last row for points in 3D space
Ami = np.array([mi]*4)
Ama = np.array([ma]*4)
for i, v in enumerate([-40,40,-100]):
    Ami[i,i] = v 
    Ama[i,i] = v 

#plot points.
ax.plot(Ami[:,0], Ami[:,1], Ami[:,2], marker="o", ls="", c=cm.coolwarm(0.))
ax.plot(Ama[:,0], Ama[:,1], Ama[:,2], marker="o", ls="", c=cm.coolwarm(1.))

ax.view_init(azim=-45, elev=19)
plt.savefig(__file__+".png")
plt.show()
```

[image]